# Populating Combobox on a Second UserForm

Tags: excel, combobox, userform, vba

I've created a `Userform` that requires the user to fill in a number of text boxes and combo boxes. A portion of the form has a command box that opens a second `Userform` (Userform 1). I've managed to set it up, but the combo boxes for the second userform won't populate. I'm using the exact same code and reference the same `LookupLists` (a Excel Worksheet). I've also tried to give the combo box a specific value that I've entered manually (`cboSENTPROJ1.Value = 9`), but that doesn't work either.

This is the code I have for Initializing `UserForm1`:

```
Private Sub UserForm1_Initialize()

Dim cPROJ As Range
Set ws = Worksheets("LookupLists")

For Each cPROJ In ws.Range("Projects")
  With Me.cboSENTPROJ1
     .AddItem cPROJ.Value
     .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = cPROJ.Offset(0, 1).Value
   End With
 Next cPROJ

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare you text.value variables as Public Variables (at the top of the module) and then you can call the values in your combobox assignments.